# Eclipse GWT unable to click "Next" on GWT classes

Tags: eclipse, gwt, module

I am trying to run my "Hello world" in GWT and using Eclipse. But I cannot create a module.

I right click on my package in the src-folder. Then I click other, find GWT classes, and choose Module. When I want to click next, it does not move to "next".

The next button works for all other gwt classes.

My download progress has been the following:

1. Download eclipse
2. Download the gwt plugin from the marketplace
3. Download the 2.9 sdk

Creation of the project progress:

1. New GWT Application project
2. Write name of project and package
3. Click so generate sample code is off
4. I create it, but get the following error:

   ```
   The project description file (.project) for 'new project' is missing. This file contains important information about the project. The project will not function properly until this file is restored.
   ```

My attempt at creating the module:

1. Right click of package in src
2. Click other
3. Find gwt classes
4. Click on module
5. Click on next
6. Nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, personally, use Maven and have not to deal with the Eclipse set up. There are several places where you can generate a ready-to-go GWT project:

- https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes
- https://github.com/NaluKit/gwt-maven-springboot-archetype
- http://www.mvp4g.org/boot-starter-nalu/BootStarterNalu.html

Follow the instructions on the page or inside the project to get it working.

Comment: So with these "archetypes" you create a maven project and then modules and etc. through that? Is there a UI and so on.

I mainly code in Android. Is there a way to include gradle through maven or something of that sort?

Comment: With this artifact builder you create a runnable project with a clinet and server part. Starting from that, you can add your code. What do you mean with 'Is there a UI ...'?